# Create a map webpart using Leaflet library in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to display a map in Sharepoint that takes locations from a list. For this, I'm trying to create a webpart using the Leaflet library (https://leafletjs.com/).
The problem is that the map is not rendering in Sharepoint. I have already imported the necessary libraries and configured the mapbox.com token.

Project is here: https://github.com/vtrlvz/leafletmap-spfx

[image: map's not rendering]

Thanks in advance!